# unable to display red color for some of the fields if there are errors using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, css

Added a jquery validation code for a form to add a text for at least one field if all the fields are empty.

That code is working fine for me but the issue is i have added a code for displaying the errors in red color but it is not working for all the fields.

It's working only for skype and email id. It should work for linkedin and name as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
      skypeid: {
        require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup']
      },
      linkedin: {
        require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup']
      },
      uname: {
        require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup']
      },
      email: {
        require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup']
      }
    },
    groups: {
      mygroup: "skypeid linkedin uname email"
    },
  });
});
```

```css
.mygroup.error {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" id="myform" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <br/>
  <h5 class="partnershipcontactus">Contact Us</h5>
  <hr>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <label for="skypeid"><b>Skype Handle</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Skype Id" name="skypeid" id="skypeid" class="mygroup">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 selectingany"><span>OR</span></div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <label for="linkedin"><b>Linkedin Profile</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Linkedin id" name="linkedin" id="linkedin" class="mygroup">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 selectinganysec"><span>OR</span></div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <label for="name"><b>Name</b><span class="mandatory"><font color="red">*</font></span></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name" name="uname" id="uname" class="mygroup">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <label for="email"><b>Email</b><span class="mandatory"><font color="red">*</font></span></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" id="email" class="mygroup">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <label for="phonenumber"><b>Contact Number</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber" class="mygroup">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="clearfix">
      <button id="submit" name="submit_contact" type="submit" class="signupbtn">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

jsfiddle link:  https://jsfiddle.net/jdqox5y0/

Comment: fyi, as you can see in your fiddle `</div></form>` that `</div>` is superfluous. Not sure if related to your question

Comment: [the font tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) is obsolete and should not be used.  your use of the b tag seems to be semantically incorrect - if you are just using it to bold items, use the span and style it, if you are wanting to emphasise the text and make it bold, use the strong tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b

Comment: @Pete ok i got that but my problem is it is displaying red color only for some fields if i click on submit button without filling any details that was my problem

Comment: `jQuery(...).validate is not a function`. In the JS fiddle you shared. The function validate is not executing. Maybe try using a different version of jquery.validate and jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove your groups option if you want to show an error message after each input:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
      skypeid: {
        require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup']
      },
      linkedin: {
        require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup']
      },
      uname: {
        require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup']
      },
      email: {
        require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup']
      }
    },
  });
});
```

```css
.mygroup.error::placeholder {
  color: red !important;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="post" id="myform" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <br/>
  <h5 class="partnershipcontactus">Contact Us</h5>
  <hr>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <label for="skypeid"><b>Skype Handle</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Skype Id" name="skypeid" id="skypeid" class="mygroup">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 selectingany"><span>OR</span></div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <label for="linkedin"><b>Linkedin Profile</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Linkedin id" name="linkedin" id="linkedin" class="mygroup">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 selectinganysec"><span>OR</span></div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <label for="name"><b>Name</b><span class="mandatory"><font color="red">*</font></span></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name" name="uname" id="uname" class="mygroup">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <label for="email"><b>Email</b><span class="mandatory"><font color="red">*</font></span></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" id="email" class="mygroup">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <label for="phonenumber"><b>Contact Number</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber" class="mygroup">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="clearfix">
      <button id="submit" name="submit_contact" type="submit" class="signupbtn">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Color should come red for place holder like how others are getting

Comment: See edit - you need to target the placeholder then, not the input